# MVC and repository pattern data efficiency

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, performance

My project is structured as follows:

**DAL**

```
public IQueryable<Post> GetPosts()
{
        var posts = from p in context.Post select p;

        return posts;
}
```

**Service**

```
public IList<Post> GetPosts()
{
        var posts = repository.GetPosts().ToList();

        return posts;
}

//Returns a list of the latest feeds, restricted by the count.
public IList<PostFeed> GetPostFeeds(int latestCount)
{
       List<Post> post - GetPosts();

       //CODE TO CREATE FEEDS HERE

       return feeds;

}
```

Lets say the GetPostFeeds(5) is supposed to return the 5 latest feeds. By going up the list, doesn't it pull down every single post from the database from GetPosts(), just to extract 5 from it?

If each post is say 5kb from the database, and there is 1 million records. Wont that be 5GB of ram being used per call to GetPostFeeds()?

Is this the way it happens? Should I go back to my DAL and write queries that return only what I need?

Comment: You should consider extracting a POCO-style interface for Post so the layer that calls the Service layer doesn't have to know about the Post class.  I am guessing that Post is a Linq-to-SQL class with table mappings and stuff decorated in?  One of the benefits of the repository pattern is to completely abstract out your data implementation and you can't do that if your main layer has to reference your data objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're working with `IQueryable`, query execution can be deferred. The query is executed once you call `ToList()` or do something else that requires data to be fetched (e.g. iterating over a child collection).

I don't think you need to worry about your DAL too much as I like to keep them fairly lean. You could take advantage of using deferred execution by rewriting your `GetPostFeeds` method though, e.g.:

```
//Returns a list of the latest feeds, restricted by the count.
public IList<PostFeed> GetPostFeeds(int latestCount)
{
   var posts = repository.GetPosts();

   // Perform additional filtering here e.g:
   posts = posts.Take(5);

   return posts.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get lazy execution until you execute ToList().  At that point, yes, the whole kit and caboodle is pulled down.

If you want more intelligent execution, consider eliminating the `ToList()` call.  Using `IQueryables` throughout the call chain will allow your repository to retrieve only the five records you need.

Once you have only the five records you need, then you can call `ToList()`.

Comment: So if I remove the ToList(), and inside the GetPostFeeds function, if i take the top 5 sorted by date, its only that is pulled from the database, or is it still everything?

Comment: Yes, that would work. The principle is to call `ToList()` *after* you have done a `.Where()` to get it down to the five records you need. Calling ToList() will force immediate execution, so do the filtering first, *before* calling ToList().

Comment: You said I should change from IList to IQueryable inside the Service also?

Comment: Yes, just pass the `IQueryable` through your service layer `GetPosts()` method to the `GetPostFeeds()` method, and return your `IList` from that.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed that by leveraging IQueryable you can avoid returning the entire table.  If you don't want IQueryable to leak out of your DAL, you might consider moving the take() call into the DAL by expanding the contract so that the DAL exposes a method that accepts a "top n" parameter.